# pythonxy and spyder fail to start -- type error in ConfigParser.py

Tags: python

have been using Spyder via PythonXY and today it stopped working.  I seem to be able to start the other utilties in the PythonXY program folder (eg, Mayavi, Ipython console, etc) but neither PythonXY or Spyder will start properly.  When I start them from the command line I get the following error trace.  Any suggestions on how to fix this (already tried uninstalling and reinstalling pythonxy/python)?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\xyhome.pyw", line 20, in <module>
    from xy import xyhome
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xy\xyhome.pyw", line 60, in <module>
    from xy.config import (CONF, STARTUP_PATH, LOG_PATH, PLUGINS, XY_VERSION,
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xy\config.py", line 40, in <module>
    CONF = UserConfig('xy', defaults=DEFAULTS, version=__version__, subfolder='.
xy')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xy\userconfig.py", line 110, in __init__
    if version != self.get_version(version):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xy\userconfig.py", line 130, in get_versio
n
    return self.get(self.DEFAULT_SECTION_NAME, 'version', version)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xy\userconfig.py", line 266, in get
    self.set(section, option, default)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xy\userconfig.py", line 332, in set
    self.__save()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xy\userconfig.py", line 167, in __save
    self.write(conf_file)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ConfigParser.py", line 407, in write
    fp.write("[%s]\n" % section)
TypeError: must be unicode, not str
>>>
```

when I print out the conf_file from the last userconfig.py call the parameter does appear to be unicode:

```
<_io.TextIOWrapper name=u'C:\\Users\\rclement\\.xy\\.xy.ini' encoding='utf-8'>
```

---

I was able to obtain a working re-installation by deleting the C:\Python27 directory and the associated sub-directories left by non-pythonxy installed packages. No registry changes were made and the Windows environment PATH settings were left as I had set them.  I still do not know the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I did a quick fix for this error

```
    for section in self._sections:
        fp.write("[%s]\n" % unicode(section)) #forced conversion to unicode
        for (key, value) in self._sections[section].items():
            if key == "__name__":
                continue
            if (value is not None) or (self._optcre == self.OPTCRE):
                key = " = ".join((key, str(value).replace('\n', '\n\t')))
            fp.write("%s\n" % (unicode(key))) #forced conversion to unicode
        fp.write(u"\n") #forced conversion to unicode
```

This quick fix worked for me. But no idea what caused the problem. :-(